# How to do width:null with Typescript react-native styles?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I know `width:null` have a special meaning, but its showing error in typescript. I want to do it **without** using `strictNullChecks:false`

Comment: Actually the proper use would be `width: undefined` and not `width: null`, because `width` can either be of type `string`, `number` or `undefined`. That's why TS is complaining when trying to set `width` to `null`

Comment: @Kapobajza But by using `width: undefined`, my purpose is not solved

Comment: Then you'll have to use [ts-ignore](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) or similar, because that's non-standard TS usage

Comment: @Kapobajza I can't that's why I asked, 

Comment: Desperate times call for desperate measures, you can do `width:null!`